# mono develop don´t show reference node

Tags: ironpython, monodevelop

I use mono develop 2.4 in ubuntu 10.10, with monodevelop-python and ironpython

When I created a empty python project mono develop don't show the reference node.

how I can add a new reference file ?

Answer (score 0):

The Python addin is for cpython, not IronPython, so it doesn't support assembly references.